# Sharing apk among users will reflect in Google play store download count?

Tags: android, download, google-play, apk, share

i am Sharing apk among users instead of letting them to download from google play store. will this reflect on my google play store download count?

Comment: Nope. Google Play will only count app installs off the Play Store. Both the website and the app. It won't even count installs off third party distributions such as Amazon, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Google play only shows the number of download through Google Play.

You could integrate https://get.fabric.io/ 
It can count any kind of downloads (Amazon downloads and installs from apk files for example)

Answer (score -1):

If you are install the application from google play store then app stores will
pick up the unique identifier(like device id) of your device. Because each device has it's own unique identifier. So if you are Sharing apk to other device how google play store will get your device identifier. And the number of downloads won't increase if you keep uninstalling and reinstalling the app on your phone. They're smart, they'll know if you download the app again on the same device (with the same identifier).